# How do I setup a fine grained preseed with tasksel set to manual?

Tags: 13.04, server, apt, ubiquity, preseed

I am trying to preseed a [netboot](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/) install of Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) x64.

### Work Setup

My preseed configuration works fine as long as `tasksel` is not set to *manual*. For example:

```
[...]
d-i base-installer/install-recommends   boolean false
d-i base-installer/kernel/image select  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic

tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect minimal
d-i pkgsel/include string      \
    lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-default-settings plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text  \
    anacron ca-certificates acpi-support dbus-x11 lxpanel lxsession openbox pcmanfm ttf-dejavu-core  \
    fonts-freefont-ttf xinit x11-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-vmware  \
    xserver-xorg-video-radeon gvfs alsa-utils policykit-1-gnome lxappearance-obconf lxrandr lxterminal  \
    localepurge deborphan synaptic iotop curl p7zip-full

d-i preseed/late_command    string  \
    wget http://11.11.11.62/share/preseed_late.sh -qP /target/tmp/;    \
    chmod 777 /target/tmp/preseed_late.sh;   \
    chroot /target/ /tmp/preseed_late.sh
[...]
```

This works readily in a virtual machine.

### The Problem

However, as soon as I set `tasksel` to *manual*, `aptitude` conflict resolution grinds to a halt with hundreds of `<package>:i386` wanting to be installed. For example:

```
[...]
d-i base-installer/install-recommends   boolean false
d-i base-installer/kernel/image select  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic

tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect manual
d-i pkgsel/include string      \
    ubuntu-standard

[...]
```

This simple preseed leads to an `aptitude` manual configuration screen with 282 broken packages, all of them being i386 variants of the dependencies of ubuntu-standard, while the amd64 variants has been or was being installed. Manually deselecting the conflicting i386 packages seems to fix each specific conflicts (I did not deselect all the packages).

I do not know how these `<package>:i386` crept up. I tried using ubuntu-minimal or ubuntu-standard:amd64 at `pkgsel/include` with no success, even by setting `base-installer/install-recommends` to *true*. I searched for a preseed option to force the architecture in [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html) and debian documentation (wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) but to no avail.

### The Goal

My intent was to simply further slim down the install footprint and get finer grained control over what packages should be installed. I know that I could use Ubuntu Core (wiki.ubuntu.com/Core), however I would prefer a preseed specific solution.

Hence, I would geatly appreciate some pointers on how to properly setup a preseed with *manual* `tasksel` and how can I fix the i386 package installation issue (it might just be a bug specific to 13.04 x64).

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://books.google.com/books?id=jQhvAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=preseed+%22manual+tasksel%22&source=bl&ots=8WuRjEx5BA&sig=rc1m8nPvcf8yn6FO_YOjtPnce8w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e0uoU73WFMOGyASd74HQCA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=preseed%20%22manual%20tasksel%22&f=false